# php redirect using header location and transferring variables

Tags: php, html

I read all the related questions on SO and google but still could not get any answer for the same..

this is my html form code

```
<form id="Form1" name="Form1" method="post" action="page1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Your Name:<input type="text" class="input" name="txtUserName">
Your Email:<input type="text" class="input" name="txtUserEmail">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

This is my php code for this page (page1.php)
    // I m transferring these variables to other page page2.php

```
<?php
$values['txtUserName'] = 'username';
$values['txtUserEmail'] = 'useremail';
header( 'Location: page2.php' );
?>
```

This is the listening code for page2.php

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['username'];
$useremail = $_GET['useremail'];
?>
```

and somewhere below html page

```
<div class="text1">
<?php echo $username; ?>
<?php echo $useremail; ?>
</div>
```

1. I got notice undefined index username and useremail
2. echo does not display anything..
   where am I wrong?
3. also if I do not want to transfer form values, but variable $username to this second page.. how can that be done?

Comment: have you seen my edited answer??

Comment: @YogeshSuthar doing the same... buddy

Comment: After searching I end up to this question, and I have 100% the same situation to the author. I would like to transfer the $_POST value while using header('Location:'). I can't linked the page2 to the form because as the same situation, I have some process that would be destroy if I do that. And if you suggest to use session it is not good for security reason in my side. So that I find this question helpful. 

Thank you for considering my opinion in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

the action should be `page2.php` if you are sending your data to page2.php

```
action="page2.php"
```

and in `page2.php` use `$_POST` because in form you have set `method='post'`

```
<?php
$username = $_POST['txtUserName'];  // txtUserName is as name in form
$usereail = $_POST['txtUserEmail']; // txtUserEmail is as name in form
?>
```

use this in `page1.php`

```
$username = $_POST['txtUserName'];
$usermail = $_POST['txtUserEmail'];
header( 'Location: page2.php?username='.$username.'&useremail='.$usermail );
```

and use `GET` in page2.php

Comment: that I already know.. but for some reasons (validation etc) I cant transfer values to page2, hence I used this method of header location.. so ur answer is not relevant to the question.. sorry to say that.. do you mind answering exact..

Comment: @aks I think you haven't read my answer properly. You have used `action='page1.php'` but it should be `action='page2.php'`, when you are sending data to `page2.php`.

Comment: @aks `> so ur answer is not relevant to the question`. His answer is completely relevant and correct! You stated that you're getting the values in `page2.php` but currently posting the form to `page1.php`.

Comment: I think you dint read my comment properly.. I cant use action as page2.php cuz all validation is in page1.. so I used this method of header location and sending via url

Comment: @fardjad do u read less or what? I M CONSTATNTLY SAYING THAT I CANT POST FORM VALUES TO PAGE2 CUZ OF VALIDATION REASONS HENCE I USED THIS METHOD OF POSTING BY URL HEADER LOCATION.. YOU KEEP SAYING ONE THING ALL THE TIME??

Comment: @aks Don't angry on **fardjad**. You have to see your question properly, you haven't posted it properly. I edited your code, now it displays the `header` thing code. See edited answer.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar let me try this new code...

Comment: @yogeshSuthar the method you showed me "header( 'Location: page2.php?username='.$username.'&useremail='.$usermail );"
Transfers variable via url method to another page.. so those variables can be used after validation. Who cares that between $username = $_POST['txtUserName'];
and header line there are other operations done or not on $username.. is it so?

Comment: @aks in `page2.php` use your code `$username = $_GET['username'];
$useremail = $_GET['useremail'];`.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar what is your opinion regarding this??
header('Location: other_page.php?'.http_build_query($values );

Comment: @aks Yes you can use it , but the condition is `$values` should be array.

Comment: @YogeshSuthar does this not make $values an array? 
$values['txtUserName'] = 'username';
$values['txtUserEmail'] = 'useremail';

Comment: @use this `$values['username'] = $_POST['txtUserName'];
$values['useremail'] = $_POST['txtUserEmail'];`

Comment: @YogeshSuthar using your method transfers values correctly to other page header( 'Location: page2.php?username='.$username.'&useremail='.$usermail );
 But the problem is this it displays it in title bar what we are sending.. and it may be a problem related to security.. what you say?

Comment: @YogeshSuthar yeah.. definitely it is a problem.. as I changes the values in title bar.. it changed those on the display at page2.. so it is a big security issue...

Comment: @YogeshSuthar do you suggest any solution then buddy?

Answer (score 0):

Your variable should come from the name and you are using post not get

```
$username = $_POST['txtUserName'];
$useremail = $_POST['txtUserEmail'];
```

You should also use action="page2.php"

Comment: also, the form action is POST.

Comment: 3. also if I do not want to transfer form values, but some variable $username to this second page.. how can that be done?

Comment: in the url with ?username=whatever

Comment: just make your form names accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Your form is sending data with `method="post"` but you retrieve values with `$_GET['username']`. You should change `$_GET` to `$_POST['username']`.

Also, be careful to typos with `$usereail = $_GET['useremail'];` and `$useremail;`

Answer (score 0):

use this code in your page page2.php

```
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $useremail = $_POST['useremail'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<form id="Form1" name="Form1" method="post" action="page2.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Your Name:<input type="text" class="input" name="txtUserName">
    Your Email:<input type="text" class="input" name="txtUserEmail">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Php Code:
$_GET['txtUserName'] name should be same as html tag name.

```
<?php
    $username = $_POST['txtUserName'];
    $useremail = $_POST['txtUserEmail'];
?>



<div class="text1">
    <?php echo $username; ?>
    <?php echo $useremail; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: that I already know.. but for some reasons (validation etc) I cant transfer values to page2, hence I used this method of header location.. so ur answer is not relevant to the question.. sorry to say that.. do you mind answering exact..

Answer (score 0):

In php,u can get the textbox value or any input's value by calling the name of the respected input name.
so u need to cal as following as per ur code

$username=$_POST['txtUserName'];
$useremail = $_POST['txtUserEmail'];

Answer (score 0):

This statement:

```
header('Location: page2.php');
```

Besides that you're redirecting to something that's not an absolute URL, it redirects to `page2.php` without passing any GET parameters. To accomplish that, you simply append them:

```
header('Location: page2.php?' . http_build_query($values));
```